# How to compare dropdownlist text with static string

Tags: jquery, text, drop-down-menu, compare

Ok, a clearer picture (I hope)...

In the HTML I have a combobox (dropdownlist) (`id= "program"`) ie: you click and select a value. The prompt text on the combobox (dropdownlist) is "Select a program..."

Beneath this, on the page, I display a button (`id="addChosen"`). After the user has made a selection, they click the addChosen button to add the text from the combobox to the `<textarea>`, while I add the value `$('#program :selected').val()` to an array with: `programArray.push($('program :selected').val());`

Therefore, in order to help the user select ONLY valid options from the combobox, I want to stop the addition of "Select a program..."

I want to compare the text from a dropdownlist to a static string:

```
if ($('#program :selected').text() == "Select a program..."); {
    //do something here, like show an alert for now...
    alert("Come on, you cant select the instructions...");
} 
else {
    //add the selected text to a <textarea>
    $('#chosenPrograms').append($('#program :selected').text() + "\n";
    }
```

This does not seem to compare the selected text, and simply insert the "Select a program..." into the `<textarea>`.

It needs to prevent the user from being able to add "Select a program..." to the `<textarea>`

This is the complete page:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Subject Selector";
ViewBag.Header1 = "Subject Selector";
ViewBag.Header2 = "Choose the right subject - Grade 10-12.";
ViewBag.Description = "Have an idea of what and where you want to study? Subject Chooser will identify the subjects and requirements you will need to achieve your goal.";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h2>Select an institution, faculty and programme</h2>
</hgroup>



@using (Html.BeginForm("IndexDDL", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id="QueryProgrammesFormId", data_institutionListAction=@Url.Action("InstitutionList") } ))     {
<fieldset>
    <legend>Institution/Faculty/Programme/Chosen Programmes</legend>
    <label for="institution">Institution</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("institution", ViewBag.Institutions as SelectList, "Select an institution...", new { id = "institution", name = "institutionID" })
    <label for="faculty">Faculty</label>
    <select id="faculty" name="faculty"></select>  
    <label for="programme">Programme</label>
    <select id="programme" name="programme"></select>   
    <p>You can add up to <strong>5</strong> programmes to the list below:</p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" id="addChosen" name="addChosen" value="Add Programme" />&nbsp;
        <input type="button" id="removeChosen" name="removeChosen" value="Remove Programme" class="hidden" />
    </p>
    <label for="chosenProgrammes">Chosen Programmes</label> 
    <textarea id="chosenProgrammes" name="chosenProgrammes" rows="5" cols="" placeholder="Programmes selected for analysis"></textarea>
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="goButton" id="goButton" value="Analyse my Programmes" style="display:none" />
    </p>

</fieldset>

/*Tommy: Local Disclaimer to show only when the button becomes available*/
<div id="localDisclaimer" class="hidden">
    @Html.Partial("_LocalDisclaimer")
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="AcceptDisclaimer" id="AcceptDisclaimer" /> I have read the Disclaimer and wish to continue.
    </p>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/cascadingdropdown")
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cnt = 1;
    var selectedProgrammes = [];
    $(function () {
        $("#faculty").CascadingDropDown("#institution", 'Query/GetFaculties',
        {
            promptText: 'Select a faculty...',
            onLoading: function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#ff3");
        },

        onLoaded: function () {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 800, 'linear');
        }
    });
    $("#programme").CascadingDropDown("#faculty", 'Query/GetProgrammes',
    {
        promptText: 'Select a programme...',
        onLoading: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#ff3");
        },

        onLoaded: function () {
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffff' }, 800, 'linear');
        }
    });
    $('#programme').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#goButton').hide();
        }
        else {
        }
    });
    $('#AcceptDisclaimer').click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('checked', 'checked')) {
            $('#goButton').show();
        }
    });
    $('#goButton').on('click', function () {
        /* 
        replace the call to Query/Results + programmeID 
        with
        SubjectSelector/Results + SelectedProgrammes[]
        */

        //window.location.href = 'Query/Results/' + $('#programme').val();
    });

    /*
    Before allowing the user to click on 'addChosen'
    check to see that the counter is less or equal to 5
    */

    $('#addChosen').click(function () {

        if ($('#programme:selected').val() == "Select a programme...") {
            alert("please make a proper selection");
        }
        else {
            $('#chosenProgrammes').append(cnt + " " + $('#programme :selected').text() + "\n");
            selectedProgrammes.push($('#programme :selected').val());
        };

        if (cnt <= 4) {
            //                $('#removeChosen').show();
            $('#localDisclaimer').show();
        }
        else {
            $('#addChosen').hide();
        };

        cnt += 1;
    });
});
```

}

This is the function that fills the Programmes drop-down:

```
public ActionResult GetProgrammes(string faculty)
{
    int facultyInt = int.Parse(faculty);
        var programmes = db.Programmes.Where(p => p.Faculty.FacultyId == facultyInt)
                                      .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                                      .Select(p => new SelectListItem()
                                      {
                                          Text = p.Name,
                                          Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)p.ProgrammeId)
                                      });
        return Json(programmes);
    }
```

Comment: HTML woudl be handy. Could you set up a jsFiddle with a HTML example as well?

Comment: Your selector syntax doesn't look valid at all, aren't you getting a Javascript syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($('#program').val() == 'Select a program...') {
    alert("Come on, you can't select the instructions...");
}
```

Comment: Loaded the full page (MVC4 view) in the Question

Comment: It would be better if you just showed the actual HTML of the 'Select a program...' drop-down, so I could see what it puts in the `VALUE` attribute. Anyway, whatever it puts there is what you should compare with in the above code. It's probably an empty string.

Comment: The contents of the drop-down gets filled dynamically from a database. the value is an integer (Program Number) and the Display Text is the Program Name

Comment: Added the function that fills to Programmes drop-down to the original question

Comment: The problem is I don't know what value your templating language generates for the `PromptText:` option. Whatever that is, that's what you need to check for in this script.

Answer (score 0):

When diagnosing these issues its good to start by checking your assumptions:

- What does `$('#program' :checked).text()` return?
- Is that what you want?
- is `:checked` the right selector for what you want? (`:selected` also exists)
- If not how do you get what you want?

If `#program` is your `select` and not an `option` (which makes sense as `#` should be unique ID) then you don't even need a pseudo-selector (:selected etc) (kudos to Barmar for that spot)

You had a misplaced `'` in your jQuery selector which I have altered (I don't think the space before the pseudo selector is valid either), plus an alternative below

```
if ($('#program:checked').text() == "Select a program..."; {
    alert("Come on, you cant select the instructions...");
} else {

    $('#chosenPrograms').append($('#program:checked').text() + "\n";
}
```

If your options use the `value` attribute (which they should as it allows you to separate the visible from the value) then try:

```
if ($('#program:selected').val() == ""; {
    alert("Come on, you cant select the instructions...");
} else {
    $('#chosenPrograms').append($('#program:selected').val() + "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edited version of my original post. Must have been out-of-my-mind-tired to have missed ":checked" when it should have been ":selected" (as it is in my code)...

Comment: also, using `if($('#program:selected').val() == "")` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone that added a response and tried to help me with this.

I have just sorted the problem out:

Where I called the following:
    `if ('#programme:selected').val() =="")`
I replaced it with:
    `if ('#programme').val() = '')`
(sans the `:selected` speudo class) and now it works!!

Thanks again to every contributor here on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! You guys (and Girls) are amazing!!